# Circular depends-on relationship between 'batchDataSourceInitializer' and 'entityManagerFactory'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

When migrating from Spring Boot 2.5.2 to 2.5.3, my unit tests suddenly fail with this trace :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'batchDataSourceInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/batch/BatchAutoConfiguration$DataSourceInitializerConfiguration.class]: Circular depends-on relationship between 'batchDataSourceInitializer' and 'entityManagerFactory'
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338)
at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:123)
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
... 68 common frames omitted
```

Is this a bug in Spring Boot? What should I check on my side?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know why 2.5.2 to 2.5.3 causes the issue, but you can check here for some fixes: https://www.baeldung.com/circular-dependencies-in-spring

Comment: Thank you @jeffrey.d.m but in my understanding the circular dependency is in a Spring class (org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/batch/BatchAutoConfiguration).

Comment: hello @Samuel, did you managed to solve this issue? I'm having a similar problem.

Comment: @raffah I couldn't find yet, but I'm still interested if you have a clue

Comment: The problem is solved with Spring Boot 2.5.5 !